# Assigning multiple pandas columns using list slice

Tags: python, pandas

In Python, it is possible to assign multiple variables to objects in a list. Is it possible to do the same for a pandas dataframe for example:

```
df.Trinucleotide
0   ACA 
1   ACC
2   ACG
3   ACT
4   ACA
5   ACC
6   ACG
7   ACT
8   ACA
9   ACC

df.loc[:,['First','Second','Third']] =  df.Trinucleotide.apply(lambda x: list(x))
```

This results in **KeyError: "['First' 'Second' 'Third'] not in index"** error while separating the variables with commas does not work as well.

```
df.loc[:,'First'], df.loc[:,'Second'],df.loc[:,'Third'] =  df.Trinucleotide.apply(lambda x: list(x))

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Is there a way to do this without explicitly assigning each variable to a slice index of the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create multiple columns when using `apply`, I think it's best to return a `Series` rather than a list. You can set the column names by setting them as the index for the `Series`. So you can do:

```
# Reading your data in
df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None, index_col=0)
df.columns = ['Trinucleotide']
df
Out[9]: 
  Trinucleotide
0              
0           ACA
1           ACC
2           ACG
# etc.

new_cols = df['Trinucleotide'].apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(list(x), index=['First', 'Second', 'Third'])
)
df[['First', 'Second', 'Third']] = new_cols

df
Out[8]: 
  Trinucleotide First Second Third
0                                 
0           ACA     A      C     A
1           ACC     A      C     C
2           ACG     A      C     G
3           ACT     A      C     T
4           ACA     A      C     A
5           ACC     A      C     C
6           ACG     A      C     G
7           ACT     A      C     T
8           ACA     A      C     A
9           ACC     A      C     C
```